# Trying to target each a link with a unique font-awesome icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Trying to target each active link with an Font-Awesome icon. I am trying to use a combination os "Content:before" AND "a::first-child".

Targeting the third a-link "contact us" with an icon, not working. Tried many combinations. Is this even possible? xD

```css
.children.windowbg > a::first-child before{
  content: "\f114";
  font-family: fontawesome !important;
  padding-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<td class="children windowbg" colspan="3">
       <strong>SUB-FORUMS</strong>: <a href="#">Report Copyright Violations</a>, <a href="#">Disclaimer</a>, <a href="#">Contact Us</a>, <a href="#">Privacy policy</a>
      </td>
```

?

https://jsfiddle.net/rr78gfw1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.windowbg  a:nth-of-type(1):before{
  content: "\f114";
  font-family: fontawesome !important;
  margin-left: -23px;
  position :absolute;
  color:red;
  font-size:20px;
}

.windowbg  a:nth-of-type(2):before{
  content: "\f115";
  font-family: fontawesome !important;
  margin-left: -23px;
  position :absolute;
  color:red;
  font-size:20px;
}

.windowbg a
{
  margin-left:25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="children windowbg" colspan="3">
       <strong>SUB-FORUMS</strong>: <a href="#">Report Copyright Violations</a>, <a href="#">Disclaimer</a>, <a href="#">Contact Us</a>, <a href="#">Privacy policy</a>
      </div>
```

Some of the solutions mentioned here are not purely CSS solutions as they ask you to change the DOM structure.

You have not used the selectors rightly,There is no `:` before the before :P and `a` is not the first child.Use `nth-of-type` selector for this.

Also you cannot use `td` tags like that without a `table`.My demo is after replacing the td with a div.

Like this,

```
.windowbg  a:nth-of-type(1):before{
  content: "\f114";
  font-family: fontawesome !important;
  margin-left: -23px;
  position :absolute;
  color:red;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/rr78gfw1/1/

Comment: WOW! Thank you Varun!! :D This was the solution I was after because I did not want to hard-code HTML because it involes more work. It was linked to CMS, require so much php coding. So I needed this css method! This is such a prefect beautifully coded css solution! I was so lost, I tried a number of different couldn't get it to work! Thank you again!

Comment: @Varun Yes, of course. And with `:nth-of-type()` it's actually more obvious how to target elements that are not first.

Comment: @JohnWisher One more important thing to note,even if you had got your selector right, you have to specify `position` attribute for the pseudo selectors `:before` and `:after` to work :)

Comment: Is there anyway to get around  margin-left: -23px; ?

Comment: @JohnWisher You could try giving it in %. It will have to be relative to the main selector. So you could try with 3 to 4 . Eg: `margin-left: -3%;`

Comment: I solved it you can use:

.windowbg  a:nth-of-type(1):before{
  content: "\f114";
  font-family: fontawesome !important;
  font-size:20px;  
  display:inline-block;
  padding-right:5px;
}

Comment: @JohnWisher Thats even better :)

Comment: Thank you again Varun, I learnt so much from your response. Honestly, I was so lost. I couldn't tell my arm from my elbow with this code structure.

Comment: @JohnWisher Welcome again :)

Answer (score 0):

you give a CLASS to your link and give him a font-family

```css
.yourlink{
font-family: fantasy;
  }
```

```html
<td class="children windowbg" colspan="3">
       <strong>SUB-FORUMS</strong>: <a href="#">Report Copyright Violations</a>, <a href="#">Disclaimer</a>, <a href="#" class="yourlink">Contact Us</a>, <a href="#">Privacy policy</a>
      </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to add font-awesome icons to your links, just use an `<i>` tag as `<i class="fa fa-tags"></i>` inside your anchor tags.

```
<td class="children windowbg" colspan="3">
                            <strong>SUB-FORUMS</strong>: <a href="#">Report Copyright Violations<i class="fa fa-tags"></i></a>, <a href="#">Disclaimer<i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i></a>, <a href="#">Contact Us<i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a>, <a href="#">Privacy policy<i class="fa fa-info"></i></a>
                        </td>
```

Refer [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/dzgat8qc/) for demo

Answer (score 0):

**The other answers have preferable solutions. This one just explains errors in the code snippet**

- Pseudo-classes like `:first-child` are with a single colon, instead of two.
- `:first-child` selects (in this case) an `a` tag that's the first child of `.children.windowbg`. The `a` tag you're trying to select is no the first child, but the first of it's type. Therefore, you should use `:first-of-type`.
- To select a pseudo-element, use a colon (`:before`). Now you were selecting a `before` tag in the `a` tag.
- A `td` tag without a `table` is not valid, and the tag is removed in the code snippet, so for the sake of testing, I wrapped it in a `table` and a `tr` tag.

```css
.children.windowbg > a:first-of-type:before {
  content: "\f114";
  font-family: fontawesome !important;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="children windowbg" colspan="3">
      <strong>SUB-FORUMS</strong>: <a href="#">Report Copyright Violations</a>, <a href="#">Disclaimer</a>, <a href="#">Contact Us</a>, <a href="#">Privacy policy</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The other answers are preferable, because when you change the order of the links or add one, you need to change the CSS (and because CSS isn't for non-dynamic styling). A better solution is to add the icons in the HTML.

## Update

There is `:first-of-type` to select the first element of it's kind, usually in a certain parent. To select the last child, use `:last-of-type`. To select other children, use `:nth-of-type(n)`, where `n` is the index of the element. The first element has index 1, not index 0. For example, to select the third element, use `:nth-of-type(3)`.

But `n` is not limited by that. You can use `odd` and `even` to select odd and even elements, and you can make a calculation with `n`. Then it selects elements with an index that could be the answer when `n` is any whole number. For example, when you use `:nth-of-type(2n)`:

```
 Values for "n" |  Indices 
----------------------------
       0        | 2 * 0 = 0
       1        | 2 * 1 = 2
       2        | 2 * 2 = 4
       3        | 2 * 3 = 6
      ...       |    ...
```

This selects all elements with an index that is a multiple of 2, so all even elements. Another example is `:nth-of-type(3+n)`:

```
 Values for "n" |  Indices 
----------------------------
       0        | 3 + 0 = 3
       1        | 3 + 1 = 4
       2        | 3 + 2 = 5
       3        | 3 + 3 = 6
      ...       |    ...
```

This selects all elements, except the first two.

[Explanation from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

This goes the same for `:first-child` (`:last-child`, `:nth-child(n)`).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation of where I was going wrong. This page of responses is really important, learnt a lot of new things with one question. Thank you.

Using your suggestion, how do I select the third a-link, i.e contact-us? and put a before font-awsome icon?